# extracting an unknown substring out of a string

Tags: c, substring

I have a program returning data in the following format:

```
<CFData 0x1001219c0 [0x7fff7027aee0]>{length = 20, capacity = 20, bytes = 0x8deead13b8ae7057f6a629fdaae5e1200bcb8cf5}
```

I need to extract `8deead13b8ae7057f6a629fdaae5e1200bcb8cf5` (yes, minus the `0x`). I tried using `sscanf` and passing some regular expressions but I have no clue on that.

Any idea how to do this? Code snippets are appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to specify how you identify the hex value you wish to extact, as there is more than one.  But if you can locate it, you can throw sscanf at the string starting with the bit you want.

Comment: I tried with `strstr` passing `bytes = ` and then `sscanf` but not getting anywhere. Do you have a snippet of code I can play with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) to locate "bytes = 0x" in the input string and copy the remainder of the string (from the end of "bytes = 0x") except for the last character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* s = "<CFData 0x1001219c0 [0x7fff7027aee0]>{length = 20, "
              "capacity = 20, "
              "bytes = 0x8deead13b8ae7057f6a629fdaae5e1200bcb8cf5}";
    char* value = 0;
    const char* begin = strstr(s, "bytes = 0x");

    if (begin)
    {
        begin += 10; /* Move past "bytes = 0x" */
        value = malloc(strlen(begin)); /* Don't need 1 extra for NULL as not
                                          copy last character from 'begin'. */
        if (value)
        {
            memcpy(value, begin, strlen(begin) - 1);
            *(value + strlen(begin) - 1) = 0;
            printf("%s\n", value);
            free(value);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok` to do the trick.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char s[] = "<CFData 0x1001219c0 [0x7fff7027aee0]>{length = 20, capacity = 20, bytes = 0x8deead13b8ae7057f6a629fdaae5e1200bcb8cf5}";
    const char *tok = "<>[]{}= ,";
    char* t = strtok(s, tok);
    int take_next = false;
    char * res;
    while (t) {
        if (take_next) {
            res = t+2;
            break;
        }
        take_next = !strcmp(t, "bytes");
        t = strtok(NULL, tok);
    }
    printf("%s\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is only a sample. You should strongly consider rewriting this using `strtok_r`, because `strtok` is not re-entrant.